# DocuSign REST API: How can I configure the ttl_expired timeout for a Recipient URL

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

We want to embed the DocuSign recipient link in a custom e-mail. This can be done using the recipient URL, but it is alive for only 5 minutes. I would like this timeout to be bigger like hours or days. This should be possible according to one of the documents, but there is no documentation on how to do this. Could anyone help me out? Preferably using the Java API, but just using the REST API is also fine.

https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Embedding%20Group/Pre-DocuSign%20Operations.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to extend the period this URL is available. The preferred approach in this case is to use DocuSign remote signing which will use the DocuSign generated emails to manage the workflow. Alternatively, if you want to still use embedded signing, the URL in the email you generate will need to the generation of the one time URL and re-direction to this URL on demand.

Comment: Kinda what I expected. Thanks for the answer!